# Error building HelloWorld bada app

Tags: bada

It should be simple, but I'm getting this error when trying to build the HelloWorld app from this [tutorial](http://developer.bada.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.osp.webappprogramming.help/html/tutorials/hellowebapp_tutorial/helloworld_web_tutorial.htm).

```
make: *** No rule to make target `C:/bada/2.0.2/Model/WaveWVGA/Target/osp_rt0.a', needed by `HelloWorld.exe'.
```

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

This means that this library is not there.
Go to c:\bada\Model\WaveWVGA, hereig you can see all framwork libraries.
if osp_rt0.a isnt there, tht means your SDK is not instlled properly. Download the SDK again and reinstall